# Leak due to CreateImageRefFromTileData

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, image.createimage

does somebody know what CreateImageRefFromTileData is about? It seems to be related to MapKit because it's occuring in a UIViewController where I display a map with some location-pins. Nothing more.

But I've no further guess where it's more deeply located.

Can somebody help me?

**Update:**

**Here are some pictures showing the leak description.**

[image: General Overview]

[image: Detailed View]

[image: Responsible Caller]

Answer (score 0):

When you run the leak detector, it shows you the place where the leaked object was allocated - you now should look make sure you deallocate (release) the image properly when you no longer need it.

Edit: if the leak is within a 3rd party library, there are two scenarios:

- the leaked object is an internal object in the library, which you can't access. In this case if you don't have the source for the library, not much you can do (complain to the developer I suppose)
- if the leaked object is something that the library returned to you, make sure you release that object properly. A useful technique for figuring out what happens is playing with the app while watching the leak analyzer after every operation you do in the app - this may help locating in which branch of your app the leak is.

Comment: So, I only can see that it's coming from a library called GMM and if I click on the entry I see nothing, so actually I can not see where it's originally coming from and where it's initiated.

Does anyone know this library called GMM?

Comment: Post the screenshot from the leak analyzer, maybe someone will be able to tell. I'm also adding an edit to the answer regarding leaks within a library.